# Console.log specific elements of the same class

Tags: javascript, userscripts

I have a few elements with the same class, but I need to console.log only specific ones without console.logging every elements with the same class. For example, I only want to see element one and three of the class. How do I do that?

```
<td class="tweet"> class one </td>
<td class="tweet"> class two </td>
<td class="tweet"> class three </td>
<td class="tweet"> class four </td>

console.log($("td.tweet" ).text());
```

**Result:**

```
class one

class two

class three

class four
```

**Need Result:**

```
class one

class three
```

Comment: console.log($("td.tweet" )[0].text());
console.log($("td.tweet" )[2].text());

Comment: @Rishab - DOM elements don't have a `text()` function. (But you could use `textContent` or `innerText`, or re-wrap them in a jQuery object.)

Comment: Sorry @T.J.Crowder , i was mean to write console.log($($("td.tweet")[0]).text())

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can [`filter`](https://api.jquery.com/filter/) the collection to just the first and third:

```js
console.log($("td.tweet").filter(index => index === 0 || index === 2).text());
```

```html
<table>
<tr>
<td class="tweet"> class one </td>
<td class="tweet"> class two </td>
<td class="tweet"> class three </td>
<td class="tweet"> class four </td>
</tr>
</table>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

You can also select just the first and third using jQuery's [`:eq` pseudo-selector](https://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/):

```js
console.log($("td.tweet:eq(0), td.tweet:eq(2)").text());
```

```html
<table>
<tr>
<td class="tweet"> class one </td>
<td class="tweet"> class two </td>
<td class="tweet"> class three </td>
<td class="tweet"> class four </td>
</tr>
</table>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```